# Generating APK for testing Buildfire application

Tags: buildfire

Is there a way to generate APK file for buildfire application that is under development so that QA's can test it?

I tried looking at the documentation but did not find anything related to it. Only option I saw was to publish app to Google Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

You can test locally with BuildFire pluginTester. you can check: https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/how-to-test-your-plugin-locally

For testing on real Android builds or iOS TestFlight builds, you can reach out to BuildFire for custom builds as long as you are on a non trial app and they will be able to provide you with these.

You can always preview your app on BuildFire previewer by following instructions when clicking the "**Preview**" button in the control panel as shown below. However, features that require special setup such as (Push Notifications, In App Purchase) or plugins that require special features to be added will not work.

[image]

Comment: We are already using preview for local development but we wanted to provide APK to few users so that we get early feedback. I guess we will have to connect with Buildfire team then. Thank you.